# Python - delete columns in 2D list

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration, nested-lists

I have a 2D `list = [[1, 8, 3], [4, 5, 6], [0, 5, 7]]`, and I want to delete columns in a loop.

For example, columns with index: 0(first) and 2(last) -  - the result after deletions should be: `[8, 5, 5]`.
There is a problem, because when I delete the 0th column, the size of the list is decreased to (0,1), and the 2nd index is out of scope.
What is the fastest method to delete columns in a loop without the out-of-scope problem?

For a better picture:

```py
[[1, 8, 3], 
 [4, 5, 6],
 [0, 5, 7]]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such shortcut in python except for iterating over all the list items and removing those index values.

However, you can use pandas which is meant for some other purpose but will do the task.

```
import pandas as pd

s = [[1, 8, 3], [4, 5, 6], [0, 5, 7]]
df = pd.DataFrame(s,columns=['val1','val2','val3'])
li = df.drop('val1',axis=1).values.tolist()
```

now li will look like this

```
[[8, 3], [5, 6], [5, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data= [[1, 8, 3], [4, 5, 6], [0, 5, 7]]
index_to_remove=[0,2]
[list(x) for x in zip(*[d for i,d in enumerate(zip(*data)) if i not in index_to_remove])]
```

Comment: Hey in your solution:  

 `list_of_columns = [0, 2]
        print(list(zip(*[d for i, d in enumerate(zip(*self.csv)) if i not in list_of_columns])))`
the results is `[(8,), (5,), (5,)]` but I need `[[8], [5], [5]]`

Comment: @kuziolewski sorry i misread what you need (list of lists). Now fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy` like this:

```
import numpy as np

my_list =  np.array([[1, 8, 3], [4, 5, 6], [0, 5, 7]])
new_list = my_list[:, 1].copy()

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
>>> [8, 5, 5]
```

---

Also `numpy.delete(your_list, index, axis)` is do the same job:

```
new_list = np.delete(my_list,(0, 2), axis=1)
```

- (0, 2) is the indices of the columns 0 and 2
- axis=1 says numpy that (0, 2) are columns indices not rows.
- if you want to delete rows 0 and 2 you can change axis=1 to axis=0

Output is a little different:

```
>>> array([[8],
       [5],
       [5]])
```

---

For a pure python approach:

```
my_list = [[1, 8, 3], [4, 5, 6], [0, 5, 7]]
new_list = [value[1] for value in my_list] 

print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
>>> [8, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

L  is 2D list:

```
print(map(lambda x: x[1:], L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to keep the middle element (index 1) of each list,in that case I would suggest creating a new list. There could be other better ways, for sure. But you could try this, if this works for you:

```
twoD_list = [[1, 8, 3], [4, 5, 6], [0, 5, 7]]

def keep_col( twoD_list ,index_to_keep = 1):
   final_list = []
   for x in twoD_list:
       final_list.append(x[index_to_keep])
   return final_list

final_list = keep_col( twoD_list , 1)
```

Final output:

```
[8,5,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want only the second element and the inner lists always have at least two elements.

Pure python with list comprehension:

```py
lst = [
    [1, 8, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [0, 5, 7],
]

filtered_lst = [
    inner_element
    for inner_lst in lst
    for i, inner_element in enumerate(inner_lst)
    if i == 1
]

print(filtered_lst)
# [8, 5, 5]
```

If you want you can the reassign the new list to the old variable:

```py
lst = filtered_lst
```

The advantages of this method are:

- no need to worry about the list being altered while you iterate it,
- no need to import other libraries
- list comprehension is built-in
- list comprehension is often the fastest way to filter a list (see for example [this article](https://switowski.com/blog/for-loop-vs-list-comprehension))
- easier to read and maintain that other solutions (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

Via `itemgetter` to extract the value at `index 1`.

```
from operator import itemgetter
my_list = [[1, 8, 3], [4, 5, 6], [0, 5, 7]]
result = list(map(itemgetter(1), my_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
my_list = [[1, 8, 3], [4, 5, 6], [0, 5, 7]]

filter_col=[0,2]
col_length=3

my_list=[[x[i] for i in range(col_length) if i not in filter_col] for x in my_list]
```

u do not want to directly mutate the list that you are working on

this performs a list comprehension to create a new list from the existing list

edit:
just saw u wanted only a flat list

assuming u only want one element for the list u can use

```
my_list=[x[1] for x in my_list]
```